# "Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument " Receiving this error with Android Studio when accessing ElasticSearch Server?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, elasticsearch, qemu

We are using Elastic Search for this project. I am trying to login to an app my group and I have made but I keep receiving errors. I see this error in the Logcat when I try to sign into my app on my emulator:

```
E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument

E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

My other team members can access the server with no issues at all. Even when we have the exact same program running, they can login just fine but mine just says the user can't be found.

Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Comment: Not actually a solution, but a workaround in case some comes across this. I had the same issue in different parts of my app, specially after changing WiFi networks, and I solved it every time by restarting the emulator

Comment: @fhomovc, I was hoping your workaround would work, but I am still getting that error.

Comment: @argoebel, you ever resolve this?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766789/failed-to-open-qemu-pipe-qemudnetwork-invalid-argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766789/failed-to-open-qemu-pipe-qemudnetwork-invalid-argument)