# Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

Tags: php, android, file, retrofit

I'm trying to upload a lot of images to online server in the same time, but i can't i got this error EPIPE(broken pipe)

> 12-13 19:00:25.389 1776-1776/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe
>   'qemud:network': Invalid argument 12-13 19:00:57.960 1706-1751/?
>   E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
>   12-13 19:01:05.180 2522-22392/com.google.android.gms.persistent
>   E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire! 12-13
>   19:01:05.601 2522-22605/com.google.android.gms.persistent
>   E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified. 12-13 19:01:16.094
>   1933-2653/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 22):

This error could be seen on Android Emulator/Device Version >= 6.0.
It occurs when your app tries to send/receive request/response to a remote API that is not secure (http). That's the reason why you should stick to communicating with remote API's via a secured channel (http**s**). But you can resolve the issue by setting the *usesCleartextTraffic* attribute to "true" inside the *application* opening tag of your android manifest file.

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
```

The aforementioned tip solves the problem, but it tends to open a threat to data integrity. Thus you can make it better by setting up, and leveraging on a network security configuration file. This can be done thus;

Step 1:
GOTO res->New->android resource directory. Create your xml resource directory

[image]

Step 2: Create a new Resource File (with the name: 'network_security_config') inside the newly created xml resource directory
by navigating through (xml->New->XML Resource File).

[image]

Step 3: Paste the code below into the newly created 'network_security_config.xml' file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_site_domain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Step 4: Goto your AndroidManifest.xml file and add the code ***android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"*** inside the *application* opening tag of your android manifest file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" >
```

Comment: I tried your suggested approach but it did not help. I still get the same error message.

Comment: should we rebuild after this ?

Comment: Hi @MathiasBradiceanu this will guide you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095875/why-do-we-need-clean-and-rebuild-project-in-android-studio

Answer (score 11):

This issue was occurring in Android 9.0 for me and I fixed it by adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" inside application tag.

```
<application
    ..
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    >
```

You can find more information here: https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

Comment: is there a way to do this via the command line? I am using the emulator from the AOSP build and I do not see this option.

Comment: Worked for me.  It did give me an error about the minimum API level, but I ignored it and it works fine.

Comment: @Emre Alparslan: I tried your suggested approach but I still get the same error (see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953789/network-connection-check-in-android-always-returns-false-altough-network-is-avai?noredirect=1#comment123707133_69953789). Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Already set. Makes no difference.

Comment: I tried your suggested approach but it did not help. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I re-created an AVD, and Run the program in the new AVD, the problem was solved.
I only met it once, it worked for me, I don’t know if it will help you, if it can help you, it would be great

Comment: I think it is beginning after emulator's android updated over internet

Answer (score -3):

Open cmd and cd to `C:\Users\Username_here\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
run this command `emulator -avd device_name -wipe-data` my device name is `Nexus_5X_API_29_x86` so it would be `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_29_x86 -wipe-data` wait until you see something like this [image]

Comment: While these commands may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -4):

Go to `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager` and then select the `SDK Tools` tab, then ensure that `Android Emulator` checkbox is selected.[image]