# How to solve Phenotype API error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am building a simple Space Invaders game in Android Studio using Java. I didn't see these errors when I ran the game before. The project and other projects in Android Studio folder were running fine, but then I might accidentally hit something wrong, all of the projects show similar errors when I run the program. I am using Emulator with API 29, SDK Platform I installed is API 29, API 30.
What I tried:

- Wipe data, Use a different emulator
- Make sure package names are the same in Manifest
- Uninstalled, then reinstalled Platform Tools\

Sources I used:
[Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766789/failed-to-open-qemu-pipe-qemudnetwork-invalid-argument)
[https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53766789.shtml\](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53766789.shtml%5C)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error/22745487#comment34571006_22629568\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error/22745487#comment34571006_22629568%5C)
["unable to locate adb" using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio)

[SDK Tools I installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flM5c.png)\

Logcat:

```
2020-08-21 12:03:33.345 2100-2136/system_process E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2020-08-21 12:03:33.539 10844-10844/? E/e.spaceinvader: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-08-21 12:03:33.825 1839-1996/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2020-08-21 12:03:37.954 1948-1948/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-08-21 12:03:38.015 1946-1946/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-08-21 12:03:44.406 2100-2140/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-08-21 12:03:55.561 2339-3855/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/amvj: Phenotype API error. Event # byvc@1a946355, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    amum: 29503
        at amvp.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):27)
        at amvj.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):91)
        at amvj.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):77)
        at aabf.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):7)
        at bkdt.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at srw.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):14)
        at srw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sxw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-08-21 12:03:55.561 2339-3855/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at amvj.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):92)
        at amvj.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):77)
        at aabf.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):7)
        at bkdt.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at srw.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):14)
        at srw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sxw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-08-21 12:03:55.562 2339-4663/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetRec: [147] ajzf.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rmz: 29503: 
        at atjq.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):5)
        at atjq.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):23)
        at ajzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):1)
        at ajzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):4)
        at ajze.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):20)
        at sle.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):1)
        at bme.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):10)
        at slf.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):17)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):6)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
     Caused by: rmz: 29503: 
        at rsm.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):4)
        at amux.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):3)
        at amvp.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):7)
        at aabf.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):15)
        at bkdt.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at srw.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):14)
        at srw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sxw.run(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-08-21 12:03:55.626 2339-4663/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Volley: [147] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com/v1/GetWifiQuality?key=AIzaSyBrlVtd67QvwS_Wz0Do4ZIdOeA6ThtVczU

2020-08-21 12:05:53.238 2339-2339/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2020-08-21 12:05:53.247 2339-2339/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
```

Comment: Did you solve this in the meantime?

Comment: Faced with similar problem. Is it problem of Android Studio or device? After that my activity was closed

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by a missed error in a layout file. I had mistakenly deleted the `layout_width` attribute from an `EditText`, and when I tried to build I got the Phenotype API error.