# Why do we need Clean and Rebuild project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning Android development, and I am confused with clean and rebuild project. My questions are :

1. Under which circumstances we need to clean and rebuild project? And why ?
2. What is the difference between clean and rebuild project?

Comment: Useful to get back to a sane state when the build system gets somehow confused. It is worth a try when you notice strange inexplicable effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gradle` will maintain build cache, you can see that for your project under `app/build` folder, it contains auto generated classes, build caches which gradle will use to reduce work every time when your are building a project, doing a **`clean`** will clear the caches for project and tells Gradle to do a fresh build causing significant additional build time for the subsequent task execution.

`Rebuild` does clean first and then build the project.