# Flutter Project not running on Emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

I have just started learning flutter. I have created my first flutter project on android studio and trying to run the demo code which is available when app is created.
*Note: I have checked "create offline project" while creating project.*

1.First I was getting following error in Logcat when I ran the application:
"Please configure Android SDK" .I have already resolve this error by adding API version "Android API 30 Platform" in "Project SDK".

Now I am getting following error (My Internet Is Working Fine):
*Note: When I run my app on chrome(web) it works fine but not working emulator*

> 2022-01-12 18:55:59.820 1868-1868/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
> 2022-01-12 18:56:03.036 1868-1868/? I/chatty: uid=2000(shell) /apex/com.android.adbd/bin/adbd identical 1 line
> 2022-01-12 18:56:03.181 1868-1868/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
> 2022-01-12 18:56:22.098 445-445/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
> 2022-01-12 18:56:22.099 445-445/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
> 2022-01-12 18:56:22.525 455-455/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
> 2022-01-12 18:56:22.525 455-455/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
> 2022-01-12 18:56:41.992 944-944/? E/DnsResolver: resNetworkResult:android.system.ErrnoException: resNetworkResult failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
> 2022-01-12 18:56:41.992 944-944/? I/chatty: uid=1073(network_stack) com.android.networkstack.process identical 1 line
> 2022-01-12 18:56:41.995 944-944/? E/DnsResolver: resNetworkResult:android.system.ErrnoException: resNetworkResult failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
> 2022-01-12 18:56:41.996 944-11702/? D/NetworkMonitor/103: PROBE_DNS [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) 10047ms FAIL in type ADDRCONFIG android.net.DnsResolver$DnsException: android.system.ErrnoException: resNetworkResult failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
> 2022-01-12 18:56:42.000 944-944/? E/DnsResolver: resNetworkResult:android.system.ErrnoException: resNetworkResult failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
> 2022-01-12 18:56:42.001 944-11703/? D/NetworkMonitor/103: PROBE_DNS connectivitycheck.gstatic.com 10050ms FAIL in type ADDRCONFIG android.net.DnsResolver$DnsException: android.system.ErrnoException: resNetworkResult failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Flutter Doctor is also not showing any error
[image: Flutter Doctor is also not showing any error]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you create any emulator device? check `flutter emulators` on terminal

Comment: I have already created as you can see in the flutter doctor screenshot it is showing me 3 devices available.

Comment: try opening emulators `flutter emulators --launch deviceName`

Comment: Already done that

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53766789/10157127) might solve the issue

Comment: in android studio bumble bee 2021 1.1 Patch 3. this is fixed